# Vector image displaying wrong in Android

Tags: android, vector-graphics

When I go to import a vector image using Android Vector Asset Studio, it becomes distorted, even in the preview. One of the vectors I was attempting to use was the photo outline straight from the Material site.

Here is what it is supposed to look like: [image]

This is what it looks like in Android: [image]

Here is one other example with what it's supposed to look like and then how it looks in Android: [image] [image]

If you want any other info let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your vector drawable was damaged. How about remove it and download original image again?

Comment: @StanleyKou I did try that but no luck. I did open both the svgs in Inkscape and they looked correct.

Answer (score 2):

use `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` and also use `app:srcCompat` insted of `android:src=`

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened when I imported a local file in Asset Studio.
The imported image is below.

[photo image](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=photo&style=outline)

However, it was displayed correctly when selecting from Clip Art in Asset Studio.
The selected image is below.

ic_crop_original_black_24dp

Can you solve the problem by using Clip Art resources?

Comment: I could do that for that photo image, but since the other image is not in clip art, I would still have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly due to some **incompatibility** in vector asset importer and the svgs. You can always find another resources or use same resource by optimizing with [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to tune the SVG and try importing again.

Comment: I tried SVGOMG but unfortunately it still looks distorted. As for trying different resources, I might have to try that, though I assumed resources directly from the Material site wouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It Could be a Design issue.
Vector Asset Studio doesn't support all PSD file features. The following list summarizes supported and unsupported PSD characteristics, as well as some conversion details.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#PSD

Answer (score -1):

It may be faster solution to fix the distorted point with xml after importing SVG.

before

```
M19,5v14L5,19L5,5h14m0,-2L5,3c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM14.14,13.86l-3,3.87L9,13.14 6,17h12l-3.86,-5.14z
```

after

```
M19,5v14L5,19L5,5h14m0,-2L5,3c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM14.14,11.86l-3,3.87L9,13.14 6,17h12l-3.86,-5.14z
```